# Как получить серийный номер жесткого диска без рута?

Tags: linux, c

Необходимо получить серийный номер жесткого диска в ОС Linux.
Я реализовал это из системных файлов

```
if ((dir = opendir(("/dev/disk/by-id"))) != NULL) {
  while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if (line == 3) {
      return ent - > d_name;
    }
    line++;
  }

}
```

Но под разные компьютеры(с несколькими HDD и еще SSD) 3тий файл(line) будет различаться.Т.е 3тий файл с названием HDD не является константным .

В каком системном файле хранится информация о системном HDD?

Comment: Что такое системный HDD? Если то что смонтировано в "/", то `grep ' / ' /etc/mtab` выдаст что-то типа `/dev/sda2`, по которому можно определить через `/dev/disk/by-id` номер. Это?

Comment: UUID никак не связан с серийным номером.

Comment: Между прочим, а зачем такая информация?

Comment: @TotalPusher ну или какой-нибудь device mapper. Корень на lvm местами дефотный способ установки. Так что +1 к уточнению "что такое системный HDD"

Comment: Системный HDD/SSD-диск,на котором хранится ОС.

Comment: Посмотри исходники `smartmontools`. Там точно есть, потому что именно через него я смотрю и модель и серийник для своих нужд.

Comment: @KostyaChernyaev, ещё раз: что такое "хранится ОС"? Вы спрашиваете про linux. Здесь запущенная система может быть размазана произвольным способом (на усмотрение root) от 0 (да, нуля дисков - PXE например) до любого числа накопителей. Простой случай: /boot отдельно, / отдельно, /var отдельно, /home отдельно. Что из этого система?